# Angularjs: Create and download html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file, download

I need to create an html file with a table and download it as a xls file. Right now we have a directive that takes a table and downloads it as requested, sadly this new page has pagination and we only take the data shown from the server, so our directive does not work.
So right now I am trying to create a HTML document from scratch and download it when clicking a button.
The code I have is:

```
       var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("NuevoDocumento");
       var p = doc.createElement("p");
       p.innerHTML = "Prueba.";
```

It is pretty simple, but I want to check that everything works properly before designing the final  html.
This seems to create the html code properly, but I don not know how to download it as a file.

Also, I am not sure that this is the best approach so any suggestion is welcomed.

Thank you,

Iker

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to set a `download` attribute on the link which you click to download the file. The file content can be set as the `href` attribute value, as a `data:` URL.

I've set up a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qDPFEoh00E08p11qGox6?p=preview

Note that I've only tested this in Chrome.